# Scary javascript-keys returned from google maps p[$a, ab]

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I declared a location from google maps by clicking the map. The data is stored like this:

```
P{
  $a: -20.55231336577107
  ab: -72.3388671875
}
```

It's uncanny, why are they not just using the latitude and longitude variables? I tried to find some documentation on this without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ditto with the other 2 answers. This is the entire reason why there's a fully documented API. Instead of accessing the object variables directly. Use the accessor methods built into the API like .lat() and .lng() on a google.maps.LatLng object.

Answer (score 6):

Google's Javascript is minified to reduce bandwidth costs.

This replaces all meaningful names with very short names, to save additional space.

Answer (score 3):

The API code is optimized with the [closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)