# What do 'fa' and 'la' attributes mean in the google maps api getBounds() method

Tags: javascript, google-maps

According to the documentation, google maps api getBounds() method should return an object containing lat/long of the SW and NE corner of the map viewport. But when I call the function, it returns an object with the below attributes. Clearly these numbers do represent lat and long coordinates, but I am uncomfortable with the fa, la, b and d attribute names because I have no idea what they mean. Thanks.

```
Kg {fa: Jg, la: Fg, getCenter: function, toString: function, toUrlValue: function…}
fa: Jg
b: 72.68218111303801
d: 7.96027316995958
__proto__: Jg
la: Fg
b: -180
d: 180
__proto__: Fg
__proto__: Kg
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scary javascript-keys returned from google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11496448/710446). Most important quote there: "*Use the accessor methods built into the API like `.lat()` and `.lng()` on a `google.maps.LatLng` object.*"

Comment: You should use only the methods described in the Google Maps API documentation. In this particular case, the [`LatLngBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) result from `getBounds` has the useful methods `getCenter`, `getNorthEast`, and `getSouthWest`.